# Creating new data in database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

It's my first time tryng to use AJAX to send data to php, and i think im doing something wrong because i cant see any new data in mysql, here is what i tried.

This script calls ajax by clicking img:

```
$s .= "\n\t<td>";
$canEdit = getPermission('tasks', 'edit', $a['task_id']);
$canViewLog = getPermission('task_log', 'view', $a['task_id']);
if ($canEdit) {
    $s .= ("\n\t\t".'<a href="#">'
           . "\n\t\t\t".'<img src="./images/icons/tick.png" alt="' . $AppUI->_('Check') 
           . '" border="0" width="12" height="12" onclick="javascript:insertData()" />' . "\n\t\t</a>");
}
$s .= "\n\t</td>";
$currentTasken=$a['task_id'];
$currentUser=$AppUI->user_id;
```

This is my ajax function which sends data to php file:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function insertData()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","datafile.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("<?php echo $currentUser; ?>");
xmlhttp.send("<?php echo $currentTasken; ?>")
    }

</script>
```

And this is PHP file which receives data from AJAX:

```
<?php
$currentUser = $_POST['$currentUser'];
$currentTasken = $_POST['$currentTasken'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
if(!$con)
    die('Could not connectzzz: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("foxi" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_task_log");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($numrows == 0)
{
    $pass = md5($pass);

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dotp_task_log (`task_log_creator`,`task_log_Task`) VALUES ('$currentUser' , '$currentTasken')" ) ;

   if($ins)
        die("Succesfully Created Log!");

    else
        die("ERROR");

}
else
{
    die("Log already exists!");
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: nah, just press that img and nothing happens...

Comment: $currentUser = $_POST['currentUser'];  $currentTasken = $_POST['currentTasken']; //get rid off $ in variable passed by $_POST, also echo $currentUser in your php to see if you have this correct post value.

Comment: changed, here is what i get with firebug: Error failure xmlhttp.send("$currentTasken")

Comment: So you variable is not defined, if you have it don't include in ""

Comment: ReferenceError: $currentUser is not defined
xmlhttp.send($currentUser);

Comment: Ok you have not defined that variable. Define it. What is that, a value from a form field or div or else ?

Comment: I UPDATED Calling script there is those values

Comment: You define them outside   function insertData(), and I think they are not visible for function defined in separate script. Why you just put your function insertData() in the same <script> section as ajax call ?

Comment: Looks like my problems vanished but not i get Log file already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as below :

```
<?php
$currentUser = $_POST['currentUser'];
$currentTasken = $_POST['currentTasken'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
if(!$con)
    die('Could not connectzzz: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("foxi" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_task_log");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($numrows == 0)
{
    $pass = md5($pass);

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dotp_task_log (`task_log_creator`,`task_log_Task`) VALUES ('$currentUser' , '$currentTasken')" ) ;

   if($ins)
        die("Succesfully Created Log!");

    else
        die("ERROR");

}
else
{
    die("Log already exists!");
}

?>
```

Also your script to :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function insertData()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","datafile.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("currentUser=<?php echo $currentUser; ?>&currentTasken=<?php echo $currentTasken; ?>");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: changed, here is what i get with firebug: Error failure xmlhttp.send("$currentTasken")

Comment: Script is in the same php file. Right?

Comment: No, I think is not in the same file, as he sends post using  Ajax. I suggest him to do an  alert($currentTasken) to see if he really have that variable defined.

Comment: @TorresAlGrande : Script is in php file or not?

Comment: ReferenceError: $currentUser is not defined
xmlhttp.send($currentUser);

Comment: Yes it is in te same file as the calling

Comment: I have changed `$currentUser` to `<?php echo $currentUser; ?>`. Try to use that.

Comment: Now it's NS_ERROR_FAILURE: xmlhttp.send("")

Comment: No it writes NS_ERROR_FAILURE: 
xmlhttp.send("1415")

Comment: @TorresAlGrande : You are adding php variable into script without php tags. Please change them

Comment: Changed. I dont have any ides anymore it writes value  NS_ERROR_FAILURE: xmlhttp.send("1415") 1415 which should send but just creates an error

Comment: @TorresAlGrande : Ok now change it as below : `xmlhttp.send("currentUser=<?php echo $currentUser; ?>&currentTasken=<?php echo $currentTasken; ?>");`. The parameter name is not there.

Comment: @TorresAlGrande : Also write this : `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Now errors vanished. But there is some problems in datafile.php file here is:
`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: $currentUser in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\....\modules\tasks\datafile.php
</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: $currentTasken in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\....\modules\tasks\datafile.php
</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Log already exists!`

Comment: I've change it to isset($_POST['currentUser']) and isset($_POST['$currentTasken']) And now it looks like ok but writes Log already exists, how could this be possible

Comment: You have used query without where clause.  `"SELECT * FROM dotp_task_log"`. What you need to check in this? You are getting 'Log already exists' because now there are some entries in your table. I hope you understand my point. @TorresAlGrande

Comment: Ye thanx @Ankii Gangrade

Answer (score 1):

Working with ajax needs diferent way to thinking. I`ll give you some concepts (if you don't have yet) that will help you not only solve this problem but future problems too and save time:

- After you write server side and client side logic, **you have to test it separately.** so, test first the server side (php part): HOW? make a simple sily static form just for post data to your server side logic to test if it's saving data correctly in database and returing expeted data.
- After testing your server side, you have sure that if your application it's not working, the problem certainly is on the client side. So, we need to test it. Do you already know how to use Browser's console? In Firefox MacOS is [Command]+[Option]+[k] in Windows should be [ctrl]+[shift]+[k] it will open on the bottom of the browser, you should mark [network] to keep logging network requests, **If your client side is working, you can see the page you're requesting by ajax** and it's http status code (should be 200).
- If client side is able to call server side through ajax and you're sure it's doing because you see the post request on the browser's console but still have not saving data properly on database, maybe you have a problem on the data is sending, or it's not sending by ajax. You can test it on the browser's log too, **click on the page shown in log with right button and mark the option, maybe in english will be writen as: "Store request/response content"** (my browser is in portuguese). **after you mark this option, make a request again and click on the requested page with left button**. You will see all headers and data you sent to server side through ajax. so, check it if is nothing wrong

**This is all.** But, consider using jQuery, it's not so hard to understand and it's ajax way to work is more uncomplicated. look at this sample:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data:$('#form-id').serialize(), // gets all form fields serialized creating a string fieldName1=value1&fieldName2=value2...
  dataType: "html"
}).done(function( msg ) { // after it's done
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
  alert(msg)
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

by the way, if you have to echo some php value on any part of your html including javascript parts as you did in:

```
xmlhttp.send("$currentUser");
xmlhttp.send("$currentTasken");
```

to get variable values, you should echo it as:

```
xmlhttp.send("<?=$currentUser?>");
xmlhttp.send("<?=$currentTasken?>");
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanx i will always whatch this before starting to code ajax